# How do I get rid of unused space on LVM2 PV?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm

I have a slight problem. After resizing my Ubuntu LVM2 Physical Volume from 250G to 72G, Gparted was able to let me click on the resize button on `/dev/sda5`

[image]

But when I apply the changes it gives me this error:

[image: less than real size error]]

I want my final partition layout to look like this:

[image: gparted]

Comment: @user535733 that is how I shrunk the partition but I cannot get rid of the unused space inside that partition

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using lvm resize from a terminal or use a GUI package

You can install `system-config-lvm`:

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm
```

You can also manage your encrypted disks via cryptsetup and lvm package

For more information on how to use it, see `man cryptsetup` and `man lvm`.